# codeigniter, active record, having problem

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a problem with Code Igniter having clause.

I need to produce the following SQL with active record:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
GROUP BY A.X
HAVING A.Y = 'test'
```

But using the following code:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('A');
$this->db->group_by('A.X');
$this->db->having('A.Y','frontend');
```

Produces:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
GROUP BY A.X
HAVING A.Y = test
```

And it seems impossible to escape the string value... Or is it?

Comment: *(sidenote)* Code Igniter's definition of [ActiveRecord](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) is wrong. If anything, it's a very simply [QueryObject](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html).

Comment: How does 'frontend' produce 'test'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the having clause in a such clumsy way:

```
$this->db->having('A.Y = "frontend"', null, false);
```

Comment: This is the correct way! Thank you, accept your answer please.